# Internal Server Error ajax Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my show view I have this div:

```
<% if @question.answers.any? %>
    <div class="parent">
        <%= render :partial => @question.answers %>
    </div>
<% else %>
    <p class="hideAns">No answers yet. Be the first first to answer!</p>
 <% end %>
```

As shown from the code above, I am displaying a paragraph if the question has no answers. The problem that I am facing is checking if the question has answers again with ajax.

In my create.js.erb file, I have this block of code that hides the paragraph:

```
$("#answers").append("<%= j render @answer %>");
tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('');
$(".hideAns").css("cssText", "display: none;");
```

In my delete.js.erb file, (**This is where I am getting the Internal server error.**) I have this block of code that checks whether the question has any answers or not:

```
$("#answer_<%= @answer.id %>").remove();

<% if @questions.answers.any? %>
    console.log("has answers");
<% else %>
    $(".hideAns").css("cssText", "display: block;");
<% end %>
```

Why is it not working? Am I not allowed to put an if statement inside a **.js.erb** file?

**EDIT**

Server log:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `answers' for nil:NilClass):
    1: $("#answer_<%= @answer.id %>").remove();
    2:
    3: <% if @question.answers.any? %>
    4:  console.log("has answers");
    5: <% else %>
    6:  $(".hideAns").css("cssText", "display: block;");
    7: <% end %>
```

Comment: `DELETE http://localhost:3000/questions/36/answers/102 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: Your logs should show the actual error and what line it occurs on

Comment: I suspect you have a typo.  Shouldn't `@questions.answers.any?` actually be `@question.answers.any?`?

Comment: Yes I now noticed that, but it sadly did not work. I am updating my question with the error logs.

Comment: `@question` is nil.  Are you setting it in your controller?

Comment: Ohh, okay thanks for hinting that out. It's 3 AM :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer was to simply define the instance variable in the destroy method.

The fix:

```
  def destroy
    @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
    @answer.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to :back } 
      format.js
    end
  end
```